# Running java file inside Node.js

Tags: java, node.js

I just got the task to create a java file, that works as JavaScript under Node.js, and as Java code also. The file extension has to be .java. My question is - how can I even run the .java file in the node? I wasn't able to find anything about an issue like this.
The code itself is very simple, so the only thing is - how to run .java in node?

Comment: I recommend you google it. but basically, you can install java using npm

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-java-code-in-node-js/)

Comment: Already did. It doesn't allow you to run .java file in node, but only to implement some java code in your .js files. That's not what I need. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you must first findout a way to execute shell commands by node.js, then you can compile and run your *.java file by this commands: first "javac myFile.java" to compile it and then run it by "java myFile". See this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-run-a-java-program)

Comment: Why? If you're in the node ecosystem, why not write whatever code you have in Java in JavaScript instead?